# react native is not set up after setting up the PATH variable

Tags: shell, react-native

I am setting up react native on mac. I have installed node along with npm.

node version is v6.11.4 
npm version is 5.4.2

I have install react native, command shown on the below image. And also export the PATH, then also it shows an error that react-native command not found. Could anyone help?

[image: attached image]

After running `npm install -g react-native --verbose`, it shows following:

[image: attached image]

Comment: Could you run `which react-native` and report back the path it gives?

Comment: when i try run which react-native , it does not return any path

Comment: What does it say then?

Comment: it shows nothing, it goes on next line of command line interface.

Comment: That's strange. How about `which node` and `which npm`?

Comment: it gives path /usr/local/bin

Comment: OK, taking that `which node` and `which npm` return `/usr/local/bin/node` and `/usr/local/bin/npm` respectively I assume you don't run anything like NVM/nodenv etc so I can't think of any other potential issues, I'm afraid. However, I'd suggest running `npm install -g react-native-cli --verbose` as a good measure just to see whether it gives any indication of a problem.

Comment: Both screenshots are exactly the same, I'm afraid.

Comment: sorry for mistake, now you can see the details, i have edited the image.

Comment: Ok, now we're talking. I've seen this error before. Answer (albeit not much helpful) coming.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the command to get react-native-cli version is `react-native -version` which will show CLI version and the version of any react-native project directory you are in

Comment: but it is not taking the command, i have installed react native. If react native has been installed then it should have accept the command and show the react native CLI version at least.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this very error happening to a colleague of mine back in India. For some reason their ISP restricted the network to a level they couldn't access the NPM registry fully and the only way around it at that time was to use a VPN. Sadly I can't provide you any more info as this happened a couple of years ago.

You may want to [change your DNS settings](http://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using#change_your_dns_servers_settings) to override your ISPs' to see whether this helps but the reason why installation of `react-native-cli` is failing is that you can't access the NPM registry so it's a problem with your network provider rather than your machine.